# "duplicate merge key detected in join" in vertica

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, vertica

I’m trying to use MERGE to upsert aggregate data into a collection of tables. For each table some fields are nullable and some are not. There are two primary key declared on fieldA and FieldB. When I run the MERGE statements I receive a “Duplicate MERGE key detected in join” error. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

NB: when am truncating the target table and if any  update operation am doing  on fieldC or FieldD in temp  table and then running merge query, its working fine. But next time when any update operation happened on fieldC or fieldD in temp table and then running merge query, its giving this error.

Sample pseudo syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE target (
fieldA varchar,
fieldB varchar,
fieldC varchar null,
fieldD int not null,
FieldE int,
Constraint target_pk primary key(fieldA, fieldB));

CREATE TABLE temp (
fieldA varchar,
fieldB varchar,
fieldC varchar null,
fieldD int not null,
fieldE int,
Constraint temp_pk primary key(fieldA, fieldB));

MERGE INTO target trg
USING temp tmp ON (
    trg.FieldA = tmp.FieldA
    AND trg.FieldB = tmp.FieldB)
   
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET fieldC = tmp.fieldC ,
    fieldD= tmp.fieldD,
    fieldE=temp.fieldE

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
    FieldA ,
    FieldB ,
    FieldC ,
    fieldD,
    fieldE)
VALUES (
    tmp.FieldA ,
    tmp.FieldB ,
    tmp.FieldC ,
    tmp.fieldD,
    tmp.fieldE);
```

Answer (score 3):

At the beginning, the target table is empty, and it does not even have a projection to contain the data.
With that, the access plan becomes a simple insert. In fact, when you EXPLAIN the MERGE with an empty target and a full source, you get an empty explain plan.

```
-- here's a scenario - improved a bit - 
-- never, if you can avoid it, use a VARCHAR with no length info
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS target;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp;
CREATE TABLE target (
fieldA VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
fieldB VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
fieldC VARCHAR(8) NULL,
fieldD INT        NOT NULL,
FieldE INT,
CONSTRAINT target_pk PRIMARY KEY(fieldA, fieldB)
);

CREATE TABLE temp LIKE target INCLUDING PROJECTIONS;

INSERT INTO temp
          SELECT '1','1','A',1,1
UNION ALL SELECT '1','1','A',1,1 -- note that this is a duplicate of the row above
UNION ALL SELECT '1','2','B',1,2
UNION ALL SELECT '1','3','C',1,3
UNION ALL SELECT '1','4','D',1,4
UNION ALL SELECT '1','5','E',1,5
;
COMMIT;
```

Explain with empty table:

```
EXPLAIN
MERGE INTO target trg
USING temp tmp 
 ON trg.FieldA = tmp.FieldA
AND trg.FieldB = tmp.FieldB
   
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
    fieldC = tmp.fieldC ,
    fieldD = tmp.fieldD,
    fieldE = tmp.fieldE

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
    FieldA ,
    FieldB ,
    FieldC ,
    fieldD,
    fieldE
) VALUES (
    tmp.FieldA ,
    tmp.FieldB ,
    tmp.FieldC ,
    tmp.fieldD,
    tmp.fieldE
);
-- out  Access Path:
-- out  
-- out  
-- out  ------------------------------
-- empty.
```

Now, I execute the first MERGE, and COMMIT:

```
MERGE INTO target trg
USING temp tmp
 ON trg.FieldA = tmp.FieldA
AND trg.FieldB = tmp.FieldB
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    fieldC = tmp.fieldC ,
    fieldD = tmp.fieldD,
    fieldE = tmp.fieldE
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
    FieldA ,
    FieldB ,
    FieldC ,
    fieldD,
    fieldE
) VALUES (
    tmp.FieldA ,
    tmp.FieldB ,
    tmp.FieldC ,
    tmp.fieldD,
    tmp.fieldE
);

COMMIT;
-- out  OUTPUT 
-- out --------
-- out       6                                                              
-- out (1 row)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (1 row): 142.089 ms. All rows formatted: 142.152 ms
-- out Time: First fetch (0 rows): 5.042 ms. All rows formatted: 5.059 ms
```

And I explain the MERGE again:

```
-- out  Access Path:
-- out  +-DML MERGE [Cost: 0, Rows: 0]
-- out  |  Target Projection: dbadmin.target_super
-- out  |  Target Prep:
-- out  | +---> JOIN MERGEJOIN(inputs presorted) [RightOuter] [Cost: 7K, Rows: 10K (NO STATISTICS)] (PATH ID: 1)
-- out  | |      Join Cond: (target.fieldA = VAL(2)) AND (target.fieldB = VAL(2))
-- out  | | +-- Outer -> STORAGE ACCESS for <No Alias> [Cost: 4K, Rows: 10K (NO STATISTICS)] (PATH ID: 2)
-- out  | | |      Projection: dbadmin.target_super
-- out  | | |      Materialize: target.fieldA, target.fieldB, target.fieldC, target.fieldD, target.FieldE, target.epoch
-- out  | | |      Runtime Filters: (SIP1(MergeJoin): target.fieldA), (SIP2(MergeJoin): target.fieldB), (SIP3(MergeJoin): target.fieldA, target.fieldB)
-- out  | | +-- Inner -> SELECT [Cost: 3K, Rows: 10K (NO STATISTICS)] (PATH ID: 3)
-- out  | | | +---> STORAGE ACCESS for tmp [Cost: 3K, Rows: 10K (NO STATISTICS)] (PATH ID: 4)
-- out  | | | |      Projection: dbadmin.temp_super
-- out  | | | |      Materialize: tmp.fieldA, tmp.fieldB, tmp.fieldC, tmp.fieldD, tmp.FieldE
```

Now you see that there is a `DML MERGE` operation, which reads from a `JOIN MERGEJOIN` operation.

When you truncate `target`, the projection remains, but is empty. In fact you get the second version of the `EXPLAIN` also when the target table is truncated, but does have a projection.

You are hitting a peculiarity of Vertica, that is there because it's a Big Data platform, optimised for performance.

1. A constraint on a table, by default, is `DISABLED`, and if you want it enabled, you have to `ALTER TABLE ENABLE CONSTRAINT ...`  - by that, slowing down any mass data manipulation considerably.
2. With a disabled primary key constraint, you *can* insert duplicates - but a subsequent `JOIN` using the primary key columns of the target table - the `OUTER` table in the explain plan - will try to take advantage of the uniqueness in building the plan - and fails if it encounters duplicate keys. And it succeeds with an empty outer, target, table.

Your MERGE with a full target containing duplicate keys fails because of that.

Do you need help in removing duplicates? There are a bunch of posts with the [Vertica] tag dealing with this ...

Comment: Thanks for explanation. its very helpful to understand my doubt